# Icecast albumart from mountpoint

Tags: icecast, albumart

I.m searching and searching. Found some scripts and try that . Several Times.

All I need is a (simple) script that shows the albumart om my icecast from my stream mount point. (I send the title of the song treu butt)

Please someone can help me with this and help me with this? I.m not technical with this.

Comment: There is no way inside icecast to do this.
Your best bet would be to do this from the player that you are using and bypass Icecast by sending it directly to your webserver.

Comment: Okey than a other way. I heard that shoutcast can do it .  I have made a shoutcast stream. It's up and running now and butt sends the txt file with the metadata. Except the albumart . What is a easy script to grab or scrobble the albumart?

Comment: no clue about SC, haven't used it in 20 years